# Scribe: Not getting proper results

Tags: dynamics-crm, data-migration, data-integration, sage-erp, scribe-workbench

I am working on `Sage ERP MAS 200` and `Microsoft Dynamics CRM` integration using `Scribe`.

---

I have a chain of 5 Scribe jobs with which I am trying to compute various values and update/insert in CRM (Target):

**(1) Job 1:** This job simply transfers all the data from AR_Customer table of MAS (source) to the same table in CRM (target). Also, for few new fields (yeartilldate sales, monthtilldate sales, prioryear sales, monthlytrend), it inserts value 0.

**(2) Job 2: Month till date or Period till date:** 
This one computes the values of  Month till date sales or Period till date sales and updates in the CRM. The values for those accounts, which do not get updated, the value is already inserted as 0 (in job 1).

**(3) Job 3: Prior year:** 
This one computes the values of  Prior Year sales and updates in the CRM. The values for those accounts, which do not get updated, the value is already inserted as 0 (in job 1).

**(4) Job 4: Year till date:** 
This one computes the values of Year till date sales and updates in the CRM. The values for those accounts, which do not get updated, the value is already inserted as 0 (in job 1).

**(5) Job 5: MonthlyTrend:** 
This one computes the values of MonthlyTrend  and updates in the CRM. The values for those accounts, which do not get updated, the value is already inserted as 0 (in job 1).

---

**Issue:**

For jobs 1,2,3 and 4, there is no issue happening at all. The issue is happening in job 5. 
I have 7 steps in my job. 7th step (CRM admin) is not called by any of the steps (i.e., there is no step in workflow which passes data to this step). But, still I have not removed it for some reasons.

Step 6 in my job (Account) is supposed to do account update. I have same formula for calculating the values of MonthlyTrend on both step 6 and 7.

Following are the observations:
1> For those records, where the flow never reaches steps 6 and 7: Value of  MonthlyTrend is getting properly calculated (I could see the values when I clicked on 'Test Job') for both steps 6 and 7.
2> For those records, where the flow never reaches steps 7, but reaches step 6: Value of  MonthlyTrend is getting properly calculated for step 7, but does not get calculated for step 6 (value remains #NULL).

Also, for step 6, when I tried giving constant value (like 0 or 8), it gets displayed even in case 2 mentioned above.

---

Please let me know why this might be happening.

Comment: Request to moderator/some user with reputation more than 1500: Will you please create a tag named 'Scribe-Insight'? (More information: http://www.scribesoft.com/scribe_insight) Actually, the tag named 'Scribe' which I have used over here refers to something else, I believe and I could not find any related tag.

Comment: your question is very unclear and there is a lot of irrelevant information.  What is the intended behavior for step 5 (where you say the issue is)?  what is the current behavior for step 5?